# restricting or hiding php files from accessing source code in local server.

Tags: php, wamp, server

I have set up a  small local server in my client office, i want to restrict the people accessing the WAMP folder. But the server should run normally

1. I tried folder lock but it totally make the folder hide and i am not even able to start the wamp server
2. I don't want to use obfuscation, is there any other way to simply lock the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Start your server with a service account. Then remove permissions for the domain users and add permissions for the service account.